# How do i echo this kind of array

Tags: php, arrays

I'm having a problem when I echo their value in `errors`

```
{
    "statusCode": 200,
    "type": "form",
    "requestUri": "/form",
    "errors": [],
    "timing": {
        "form": {
            "start": 1571233919.644254,
            "end": 1571233919.947743,
            "duration": 0.30348896980285645
        }
    },
    "body": {
        "form": {
            "formResponse": {
                "success": false,
                "errors": [
                    "You have already submitted this form."
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I already tried

`echo $array->body[0]-form->formResponse->errors;` but it doesn't work

Comment: Could you please tag the question with the language you use? It will help to bring it to the attention of the right people.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `json_decode` function.
Probably your code can looks like this

```
$array  = json_decode($json);
$response = $array->body->form->formResponse;
// display success value
echo $response->success;
// display error (but only first error from array)
echo current($response->errors);
```

Where I assumed that $json contains code which you pasted above

Comment: Please notice, that $array variable in fact will be not contain array type, but object

Comment: it echo "Array"

Comment: last question how do i echo the false in `success`

Comment: I've edited my answer to answer to both of your questions